# Unable to Backup or Restore Certificate Authority?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, self-signed-certificate

I migrated Certificate Authority Enterprise from windows server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2019. Both Server are VMs

Here are the steps I took:

1. Baskup CA database, key and registry config of the windows server 2012
2. Unplug the network for the windows server 2012
3. Assign the hostname and IPs from the Windows 2012 server to the Windows 2019 server.
4. Restore CA, and registry config to the windows 2019 server.

The problem is after I have done the migration I am not able to backup the CA running on the windows 2019 server. As in the option is grayed out.

**How do I enable backup/Restore CA on the new server?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below article has a fix for this issue.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8867b73-e0cf-4787-8d07-44cd730fab99/unable-to-backup-enterprise-certificate-authority?forum=winserversecurity

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/510080)